# 2 STM32 boards with SPI

Tags: matlab, simulink, stm32, spi

2 STM32 μc (NucleoF767ZI and Nucleo F446RE) should communicate via SPI. The first µc is programmed with Simulink using the Nucleo Support Package. As it stands, the μc with the Support Package can only work as a master. Now I just want to send a number from 0-255 to the slave μc for testing. And see the message with debugging mode. According to the Simulink block parameter, the Slave address register must be entered.

Then i am going to measure the the Duty Cycle of a PWM signal and send to via spi to the Master µc in Simulink, so the µc will function as a Sensor.

```html
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
uint8_t Rx[2];
/* USER CODE END 0

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
__HAL_SPI_ENABLE(&hspi1);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1,Rx,1,10);
    HAL_Delay(50);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

So my question, is it possible that my SPI of the slave µc (e.g., SPI2) has an address?

[sIMULINK-SPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwcSv.png)

Comment: SPI doesn't use addresses, it uses a chip-select signal per slave.

Comment: Ahh, the documentation says "slave register address" but your question changed that to "slave address register".  The difference is important.  There is not a register holding the slave address.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes you are right but the Buffer has an address in the Register or not ? so i can try with it in Simulink​